# How to crop moving an (overlayed) image across a video in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, crop

I want to crop moving an image. The crop must move with the time to make a translation effect. I tried with this following command:

```
   ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "movie=filename=image.jpg:loop=1[pip:v];[pip:v]trim=start=0.0:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[pip:v];[pip:v]scale='if(gte(ih,iw),384,-1):if(gte(ih,iw),-1,216)',crop=384:216:exact=1[pip:v];[pip:v]scale=iw*(1.3):ih*(1.3)[pip:v];[pip:v]crop=384:216:-(in_w-out_w)*(t-(5))/5:0[pip:v];[0:v][pip:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-33.333332:main_h-overlay_h-33.333332:enable='between(t,0,0+5)'[outv]" -map [outv] -preset ultrafast -r 29.97 output.mp4
```

But the crop remains fixed. I think the crop timestamp doesn't work because it's an image. I can't find the solution, can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `movie` filter, you may add `image.jpg` as second input, and add `-r` for setting the framerate:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -r 29.97 -loop 1 -i image.jpg...
```

It defines the framerate (repeat rate) of `image.jpg`, and solves the timestamps issue.

---

Updated command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -r 29.97 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]trim=start=0.0:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[pip:v];[pip:v]scale='if(gte(ih,iw),384,-1):if(gte(ih,iw),-1,216)',crop=384:216:exact=1[pip:v];[pip:v]scale=iw*(1.3):ih*(1.3)[pip:v];[pip:v]crop=384:216:-(in_w-out_w)*(t-(5))/5:0[pip:v];[0:v][pip:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-33.333332:main_h-overlay_h-33.333332:enable='between(t,0,0+5)':format=yuv444[outv]" -map [outv] -preset ultrafast -r 29.97 output.mp4
```